# Implementing Thrust Binary Predicate

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to use the min_element for array of structures, but I simply can't define the binary function for that operation.

I would like to define that structure implicitly, without the  , but

Is it okay? I tried almost everything but nothing seems to work.

```
struct pred : public binary_function <bool , float3 , float3>
{
   bool operator () ( const float3 a, const float3 b)
   {
      return a.x > b.x;
   }
}
```

instead I'm getting weird errors that I'm not implementing it right and there are overloading issues with one of the types which I don't know which exactly.

Thanks for your help.

I just need an example for a working `MIN_ELEMENT` function with binary predicate acceptance.

Thanks again!

Comment: It's hard to answer your question if you don't tell us what errors you get. Also, the order of the template arguments is wrong, the result type should be last.

Comment: Hey Joachim , i will post the detailed error list right when i come back from work , but i believe that the main problem as you mentioned is the result type , for hours i've been trying to use the first argument as the result rather than the last . so this may be thing that messed everything up.i will post an updated if it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have the template arguments to the binary_function in the wrong order. The return type follows the argument types and not the otherway around. Off the top of my head, binary predicate to do the comparison you are looking for should look something like this (buyer beware, never been near a compiler):

```
struct pred: public binary_function<float3,float3,bool>
{
    __device__ bool operator()(const float3 &a, const float3 &a) const
    {
        return a.x > b.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just drop ```binary_function``` entirely. ```min_element``` doesn't need it.

Comment: hey guys , i tried it , but instead of finding the min element , it zeros most of my array..

Comment: Hey Bart , i accepted it, i hope.
well that predicate didn't work . instead , i switched my entire float3* arr to float* ... didn't manage to find out the reason...
thanks anyway :)